# Why does 101010 return `True` when the expression`str(000) in str(101010)` is evaluated in Python?

Tags: python, in-operator

I'm working on [this LeetCode problem here](https://leetcode.com/problems/largest-3-same-digit-number-in-string/?envType=daily-question&envId=2023-12-04), and I'm implementing a brute force approach as well as an iterative approach. The iterative approach works fine, but my brute force approach seems to have hit an edge case. I want to determine whether a string has 3 consecutive numbers and return the highest 3 consecutive numbers in it. My code is as follows:

```
class Solution:
    def largestGoodInteger(self, num: str) -> str:
        if str(999) in num:
            return "999"
        elif str(888) in num:
            return "888"
        elif str(777) in num:
            return "777"
        elif str(666) in num:
            return "666"
        elif str(555) in num:
            return "555"
        elif str(444) in num:
            return "444"
        elif str(333) in num:
            return "333"
        elif str(222) in num:
            return "222"
        elif str(111) in num:
            return "111"
        elif str(000) in num:
            return "000"
        else:
            return ""
```

For some reason, the string `101010` returns `"000"` even though `000` is not sequential in the string. I figured that the `in` operator may be evaluating the string `000` as an array and iterating over each element in the string, but the operator does not appear to do that [according to the docs](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/in.html). As such, why does `000` get returned instead of `""`?

Comment: If you're looking for something more elegant, I might suggest using `itertools.groupby` and looking for groups of 3+ characters.

Comment: Side note: writing leading zeros in an integer literal generally is not allowed in Python. For example, `001` would be a syntax error. The fact that leading zeros are allowed in literals for `0` is a special case. See [Why does Python 3 allow "00" as a literal for 0 but not allow "01" as a literal for 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31447694/11082165)

Comment: first you could check `print( str(000) )`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that the issue didn't have anything to do with the `in` operator, but rather how Python evaluates string conversion. No matter how many zeroes you pass to `str()`, it returns a single zero as a string. Therefore, `str(000)` returned `"0"` and since the single `0` exists in the string, the statement returned `True`. Changing it to `"000" in str(num)` fixed the issue.

Comment: _"No matter how many zeroes you pass to str()"_, note that you're not "passing zeros" to `str`, you're passing an integer object. It would be more accurate to say "no matter how many zeros you write in an integer literal for zero, it's still just zero".

Comment: Why even do the `str(777)` thing in the first place?  Just specify the string `"777"`.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid repeating each number and **keeping the same logic of your code**, you can do it in a single `for` loop:

```
def largest_good_integer(self, num: str) -> str:
    for n in reversed(range(10)):
        token: str = f'{n}' * 3    # Repeat the digit thrice
        if token in num:
            return token

    return ''
```

or using a single function call, on Python >= 3.8:

```
def largest_good_integer(num: str) -> str:
    return next((token for n in reversed(range(10)) if (token := f'{n}' * 3) in num), '')
```

The above solution also helps to avoid falling into that `str(000)` trap.

Comment: Instead of `reversed(range(10))` you could use `range(9,-1,-1)`.  Also instead of `f'{n}'` you could use `str(n)`.

Comment: @MarkRansom What are the advantages over one another?

Comment: Just a matter of style.  Some might find one easier to understand than the other.

Answer (score 0):

Another note on using "000" as a literal is that leading zero's are often interpreted as being in octal.  Here's some fun errors from my interpreter:

```
>>> 001
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    001
      ^
SyntaxError: leading zeros in decimal integer literals are not permitted; use an 0o prefix for octal integers
>>> 000
0
>>>
```

You can see that python no longer accepts the `001` and asks for you to use `0o1` as the octal literal.
Also, worth noting is that `000` results in the Integer object of `0`.  So then it stands to reason that `str(int("000")) == '0'` and in fact does.  When converting strings to numbers and numbers to strings, it's important to know what these constraints are.

General advice for writing software is to assume that what you write in the code *is not* what's going to be executed.  Rather, what you write in code is going to be interpreted by the language/compiler to something that is (hopefully) equivalent.

Comment: You can enforce the leading zeros with a f-string: `f'{int("000"):03}'`

Comment: I agree, you can do that thing.  +1 for f-strings!